# Cast the datasource of a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have the following situation:

A `UIViewController` assigned to a `UIViewController` class `MyViewController`.

In my `UIViewController` I have one `UITableView`. However the `dataSource` of this `UITableView` is not `MyViewController` but another class called `MyTableViewHandler`.

I have created an outlet for the table view (`MyTableView`) in `MyViewController`, i.e. I can access the table view from the class.

Now I want to get the data source of the table view in `MyViewController`, which should be an object of `MyTableViewHandler`.

What I have tried so far:

```
MyTableViewHandler *myTableViewHandler = MyTableView.dataSource;
```

and

```
MyTableViewHandler *myTableViewHandler = (MyTableViewHandler *)MyTableView.dataSource;
```

Debugging shows that the references are set to `nil` (`0x00000000`).

I would appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you setting the dataSource property of `MyTableView`?

Comment: First I added an object to the interface builder and set my class MyTableViewHandler on that object. Second I just used the interface builder with option click on the TableView and dragged a line from my TableView to the object.

Comment: You're going to need to include a lot more of your lifecycle code before anyone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the cast. You are probably trying to access `MyTableView` before the view is loaded. You can either call `[self view]` to load the view or put this code in some place like `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Actually I am trying this in the `viewDidLoad` method already :( In Addition without the cast I get a warning from the compiler as the return type of `dataSource` is `id<UITableViewDataSource>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of your MyTableViewHandler class first (the following code would be in MyViewController -- viewDidLoad would be a good place).

MyTableViewHandler *myTableViewHandler = [[MyTableViewHandler alloc] init];
myTableView.datasource = myTableViewHandler;